# Getting a range of elements from a multidimensional nested array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How would I create a function that would get a specific range of elements from a multidimensional nested array (example structure below)?

So for example, entering a range of 1-3 would return the first 3 elements in the array (1234, 1240, and 1352 according to the structure below). A range of 5-6 would return the 5th element up to the 6th element (1235 and 1272 according to the structure below).

I'm aware of `array_slice()`, however, that function doesn't work for my case without modification.

Here is an example structure of the array (varying depth).

```
Array
(
    [1234] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1234
            [parent_id] => 1220
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [1240] => Array
                        (
                            [post_id] => 1240
                            [parent_id] => 1234
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [1352] => Array
                                        (
                                            [post_id] => 1352
                                            [parent_id] => 1240
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1568] => Array
                                        (
                                            [post_id] => 1568
                                            [parent_id] => 1240
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )
         )

     [1235] => Array
         (
              [post_id] => 1235
              [parent_id] => 1220
              [children] => Array
                  (
                      [1272] => Array
                          (
                              [post_id] => 1272
                              [parent_id] => 1235
                              [children] => Array
                                  (
                                  )
                           )
                  )

         )
)
```

Comment: Seems like you're trying to do a depth-first tree traversal followed by an array slice.

Answer (score 0):

I would flatten the array and then use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to return the elements within your range.

Here is a function that will flatten your multi-dimensional array data structure:

```
function array_flatten($orig, $flattened) {
    foreach( $orig as $key => $val ){
        if(isset($orig[$key]['product_id'])){ $flattened[$key]['product_id'] = $orig[$key]['product_id']; }
        if(isset($orig[$key]['post_id'])){ $flattened[$key]['post_id'] = $orig[$key]['post_id']; }
        if(isset($orig[$key]['parent_id'])){ $flattened[$key]['parent_id'] = $orig[$key]['parent_id']; }
        if( is_array( $orig[$key]['children'] ) ){
             $flattened = array_flatten($orig[$key]['children'], $flattened);
        }
    }
    return $flattened;
}
```

Call the function above with your array and then use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to get the elements within your range:

```
$result = array_flatten($my_array, array()); //$my_array being an array like yours above
print_r(array_slice($result,1,2, true)); //This should return the 2nd and 3rd elements
```

I have a working version [here](http://codepad.org/VmBsVTa4).

Disclaimer: it's not the most efficient way to do it since you're walking the full length of the array, but assuming the array is modest in size, it should work.

Comment: Doesn't flattening the array take away its structure?

Comment: You're not flattening/changing the original array in any way, you still have access to it if you need it. Instead, you're creating a separate flattened representation of it so you can access a range of elements within it easily.

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for is a way to *recursively iterate* through the data. I'm not completely sure what the end goal should be and what exactly your desired behavior is, but here is an example of a `RecursiveLimitIterator` that basically just is a `\FilterIterator` with some custom rules. See the commented out parts in the `accept()` method for a way to alter the desired result:

```
class RecursiveLimitIterator extends \FilterIterator
{
    private $offset, $limit;
    private $counter = 0;

    /**
     * @param \Iterator | \Countable $iterator
     * @param int                    $offset
     * @param int                    $limit
     */
    public function __construct( \Iterator $iterator, $offset = null, $limit = null )
    {
        $this->offset = $offset ?: 0;
        $this->limit  = $limit  ?: $iterator->count() -1;
        parent::__construct( $iterator );
    }

    public function accept()
    {
        $current = parent::current();
        $valid = 'children' === $this->key()
            # || is_int( $this->key() )
            && ! empty( $current );

        $valid and $this->counter++;

        return $valid
            and $this->counter >= $this->offset
            and $this->counter <= $this->limit;
    }
}
```

### How to loop

```
$it = new RecursiveLimitIterator( new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new \RecursiveArrayIterator( $test ),
    \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
), 0, 2 );

$it->rewind();
while ( $it->valid() )
{
    var_dump( $it->current() );
    $it->next();
}
```

### Result

With the current `accept()` internals, the Iterator results (while using below test data set) in the following:

```
array (size=1)
  1240 => 
    array (size=3)
      'post_id' => int 1240
      'parent_id' => int 1234
      'children' => 
        array (size=2)
          1352 => 
            array (size=3)
              'post_id' => int 1352
              'parent_id' => int 1240
              'children' => 
                array (size=1)
                  1414 => 
                    array (size=3)
                      'post_id' => int 1352
                      'parent_id' => int 1240
                      'children' => 
                        array (size=0)
                          empty
          1568 => 
            array (size=3)
              'post_id' => int 1568
              'parent_id' => int 1240
              'children' => 
                array (size=0)
                  empty
array (size=2)
  1352 => 
    array (size=3)
      'post_id' => int 1352
      'parent_id' => int 1240
      'children' => 
        array (size=1)
          1414 => 
            array (size=3)
              'post_id' => int 1352
              'parent_id' => int 1240
              'children' => 
                array (size=0)
                  empty
  1568 => 
    array (size=3)
      'post_id' => int 1568
      'parent_id' => int 1240
      'children' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
```

#### Testdata for other answers

Use the following data set if you want to play around with the code:

```
$test = [
    1234 => [
        'product_id' => 1234,
        'parent_id'  => 1220,
        'children'   => [
            1240 => [
                'post_id'   => 1240,
                'parent_id' => 1234,
                'children' => [
                    '1352' => [
                        'post_id'   => 1352,
                        'parent_id' => 1240,
                        'children' => [
                            '1414' => [
                                'post_id'   => 1352,
                                'parent_id' => 1240,
                                'children' => []
                            ],
                        ]
                    ],
                    1568 => [
                        'post_id' => 1568,
                        'parent_id' => 1240,
                        'children' => []
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    1235 => [
        'post_id'   => 1235,
        'parent_id' => 1220,
        'children'  => [
            1272 => [
                'post_id'   => 1272,
                'parent_id' => 1235,
                'children'  => [],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```